# How to increase the Page Speed in PWA (Progressive Web App) By using ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, progressive-web-apps

How can I increase the page speed for my PWA web application by using `ionic 3` ?

I had check speed for my pwa web application it shows 0. How can I increase the speed for it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to check the speed of your app?

There are several technoques you can use to improve the performance of your web app. In case of a PWA, I would suggest to implement the proper caching strategies, so that you can save network calls and deliver data from the local cache.

For example the `cache first` strategy, always attempt to deliver the requested assets from the cache, falling back to network if nothing is found.

Hava a look at this article describing in detail [how Service Workers function](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f) and which caching strategies you can adopt in your context.

Comment: You can try to pre cache some core assets with "Performance" strategy. Then  you can also plan to cache some HTTP GET calls for some endpoints that might be slow. After that you can retest the page speed of your application. However if you could upload some screenshots with the Analysis result it would be easier to suggest you how to proceed.